# How can call method onEndEdit inputfield or Ok button clicked in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I have an InputField for search terms in my application witch develop with unity.

On android mobile device , I need to find when Ok or Done clicked by user or edit the inputfield end to call a method to doing search.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, After try many code and document !  solved it :

```
public void Start()
{
    //Adds a listener that invokes the "LockInput" method when the player finishes editing the main input field.
    //Passes the main input field into the method when "LockInput" is invoked
    termInputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate { LockInput(termInputField); });
}


void LockInput(TMP_InputField input)
{
    if (input.text.Length > 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Text has been entered");
        DoSearch();
    }
    else if (input.text.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Main Input Empty");
    }
}



public void DoSearch()
    {
//My Code For Doing Search!
}
```